# Read Event Log on Windows Server 2003

Tags: c#, windows-server-2003, event-log

I wrote a program to read the event log, and it works great on Windows server 2008, however when I run it on Windows Server 2003 it throws an exception "Operation is not supported on this platform".  I know it's caused by the EventLogReader class.  So my question is, how can my program read the event log on a Windows Server 2003?

Comment: Can you show us the code and the line where the problem happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create an instance of the [EventLog Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and then iterate through the collection in the [EventLog.Entries Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.entries%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).